# Add custom action in Sylius resource grid

Tags: grid, symfony, sylius

I have created a grid from a custom Resource (Newsletter), and I would like to add, on each line, a "send" button, next to the defaut "edit" and "delete" buttons.
But I don't know how to defined a custom action in the grid definition and I don't find the info in the Sylius docs...

Here is my grid def :

```
sylius_grid:
    grids:
        admin_newsletter:
            driver:
                name: doctrine/orm
                options:
                    class: NewsletterBundle\Entity\Newsletter
            sorting:
                date: desc
            fields:
                titre:
                    type: string
                    label: sylius.ui.title
                    sortable: ~
                date:
                    type: datetime
                    label: sylius.ui.date
                    sortable: ~
                    options:
                        format: d/m/Y
                envoye:
                    type: twig
                    label: admin.ui.newsletter_envoye
                    sortable: ~
                    options:
                        template: NewsletterBundle:Helper:_sent.html.twig
            filters:
                search:
                    type: string
                    label: sylius.ui.search
                    options:
                        fields: [titre]
            actions:
                main:
                    create:
                        type: create
                item:
                    update:
                        type: update
                    delete:
                        type: delete

                    # This is what I want: 
                    send: 
                        type: send
```

Any idea of how to do that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that all you need to do is add your own Action template (AppBundle/Resources/views/Grid/Action/send.html.twig),

and then configure it in the app/config/config.yml:

just like the default actions are defined here: https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/AdminBundle/Resources/config/app/config.yml#L34

```
sylius_grid:
    templates:
        action:
            send: "@AppBundle/Grid/Action/send.html.twig"
```

Check the template path, because I am not sure of it.

Comment: That's it ! Tks CoderMaggie :)